# OnActivityResult() is not called

Tags: android, android-intent

OnActivityResult() is not called when control goes to the firstActivity on Samsung Galaxy Ace(Android version 2.3.6) but it works appropriately on Samsung galaxy fit(Android version 2.3.6). Please help me...

Following is my code :

In First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,CameraActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 

          photo =  data.getByteArrayExtra("image_data");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo ,0,photo.length);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,75, bos);
        data1 = bos.toByteArray();
        bab = new ByteArrayBody(data1, ""+ ConsumerNo.getText() +".JPEG");
    }

}
```

In Second Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {



        data1 = data;
        if(data1 == null)
        {
            Log.d("==========>>>>>", "nuuullllllllllllll");
        }
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        saveButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        newButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        ImageView imageBut= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,75, bos);
        imageBut.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(CameraActivity.this);


        newButton.setOnClickListener(CameraActivity.this);

    }


         if(((Button)v).getId() == saveButton.getId())
    {
        intent = getIntent();

        intent.putExtra("image_data", data1);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to do a switch case statement to handle the requestCodes.

In this case, do this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  switch(requestCode){

  case 2: //2 since you started your intent with 2 as the requestCode
    if  (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
         //your code here
    }
    break;
  }

}
```

Comment: If it works, upvote and accept as answer as to help those who would have the same problem and see your question.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply..But Method is not called,I just printed some logs just after "super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)" in onActivityResult() statement and it is not get printed on logcat.

Comment: Try printing a log in your CameraActivity Class

Comment: I have Printed logs in CameraActivity and it get displyed in logcat also. Application is working fine on Samsung galaxy fit but it is not working on Samsung Ace, however both the phones have same Android versions i.e 2.3.6 but kernel versions are different. On Samsung galaxy fit "OnActivityResult()" gets called and application is working fine. I am not getting what's the reason behind this?